# Going back to school with H1B

Tags: usa, working-visas, student-visa, h1-visa

I went to school in the U.S. in 2009 for my PhD and graduated in 2014. Got my H1B just this year, but I want to go back to school for another masters (I want more electrical engineering training). I have several questions:

1. Is this possible to do? (H1B to F1 or something)
2. Can I do internships in the U.S. if I go back to school in the U.S.?
3. Can I work in the U.S. again after I graduate?

If I want to work in the U.S. after getting this masters, what are possible ways to do this (besides getting married to an American)?

I am from China.

Answer (score 1):

> Is this possible to do? (H1B to F1 or something)

Sure. You need to change status back to F1/J1 (student visas).

> Can I do internships in the U.S. if I go back to school in the U.S.?

Sure, as part of your F1 you can do internships.

> Can I work in the U.S. again after I graduate?

Sure. As part of your F1, you can do OPT. However, since it will likely be more than a year after you started studying, you'll loose the H1b quota currently assigned to you and your prospective employer will have to apply for a new H1b for you, and participate in the lottery again.

Comment: does it matter if I completed a PhD already? I was under the impression that this was only available to those completing undergraduate/masters degrees. Are there any such restrictions? Also, can I do internships while I am back in school (through CPT or something?). Does it matter if I've already used an OPT once before? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @sazuhabe no, no, yes, no. What matters is that you need to be a full time student for 2 years to qualify for OPT.